# Node.js -- http.get failing on Mac OS X

Tags: node.js

I've been trying to get simple Node queries to work and my script is failing every time. I've resorted to using the demo call from the node manual, but my own calls fail with the same error.

```
var http = require('http');

http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

The error I receive is:

```
Assertion failed: (args[2]->Uint32Value()), function Connect, file ../src/tcp_wrap.cc, line 368.
Abort trap: 6
```

One last thing to mention is that the `http.get()` function is operating inside of a `setInterval()` timer. I've tested it outside the loop and it still throws the same error.

Comment: This is an internal Node.js error.  What version are you running?  Did you build it yourself?

Comment: Works for me on Node v0.11.3 from MacPorts.